# Json stringify double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I can't seem to get around this issue... Json I'm trying to pass to an MVC Controller keeps coming out like this

```
"\"{MaterialQuantity: { MaterialID :18, Quantity:1}}\""
```

This is the code that generates it:

```
function CreateJsonForQuantities() {
    var inputs = $('input[name=MaterialQuantity]');
    var total = inputs.length;
    var data = "";

    inputs.each(function (index) {
        data = data + $(this).val();
        if (index != total -1)
            data = data + ',';
    });

    return data;        
}
```

And this is the hidden which it reads data from (of course this is auto-generated as well)

```
<input name="MaterialQuantity" type="hidden" value="{MaterialQuantity: { MaterialID :12, Quantity:5}}" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Ok so now I'm properly getting json object and my ajax requests looks like this. Problem now is that it does pass proper objects but all values are null in the controller action :(

```
var form_data = CreateJsonForNorm();
var quantity_data = CreateJsonForQuantities();
var data = { norm: form_data, mqvm: quantity_data };
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: form.attr("action"),
   data: data,
   success: function () {
       location.href = "@Url.Action("Index")";
       ('#addDialog').dialog("close");
   },
   error: function () {
       alert("Error");
   }
});
```

Comment: What you have in the value attribute isn't JSON. See http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ahhhh... So I should parse it with JSON.parse?

Comment: You can't parse it with JSON.parse. It isn't JSON. You should create it with a JSON serializer.

Comment: Then how to make it JSON? :S

Comment: The main problem is missing double-quotes around the property names, but even if you fix that the output of your function won't be JSON either because it will be `{...},{...},etc` - to be valid JSON that would need to have square brackets around it: `[{...},{...},etc]` to make it an array.

Comment: Ahhhh... I seem to have made a stupid mistake... is there a way to put json in hidden value when i have only those two integers?

Comment: `value='{"MaterialQuantity":{"MaterialID":12,"Quantity":5}}'` - that is, use single quotes for the html `value` attribute, then you can add double quotes around the property names in your string to make it valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks I will do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.stringify(data)` in your request